# Bulk move documents between CouchDB databases

Tags: couchdb

Our database is getting too large and we need to archive older records off to an archive database based on a filter (namely a Created date field). What's the fastest and easiest way to accomplish this? Most languages are acceptable as long as the code is easy to understand and maintain.

This would need to be a task that can be scheduled to run regularly, e.g. weekly.

Answer (score 2):

You can employ this strategy:

1) Set up uni-directional filtered replication, see http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Replication#Filtered_Replication. Your filter function must detect and reject both newer docs and deletions.

2) Optionaly add `validate_doc_update` function to target DB. It can also reject deletions – to ensure no del operation can get through accidentally. Something like

```
validate_doc_update: function(newDoc, oldDoc, uCtx, sec) {
  if (oldDoc && newDoc._deleted) throw ({forbidden:'Can’t delete from archive'});
}
```

3) Create view index in the source bucket to fetch doc list for weekly purge.

4) Set up repeated task, that performs replication, and, if succeeded, batch-delete docs, and, if succeded, perform source DB compaction.

Batch deletion is better performed using `_bulk_docs` – you can POST array of docs with `_deleted` property set to true. To ensure you source DB does not stash deleted docs even after compaction, you must set `_revs_limit` to 1 (http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/database/misc.html#db-revs-limit).

To ensure no docs disappear during process you better keep date range of replication significantly wider then deletion date range. If you delete, for example, docs older than 28 days (4 weeks) every sunday, you must first replicate docs older than 20 days (3 weeks minus 1 day).

Comment: Or perhaps you could employ continuous replication to a backup database - filtering out deletes as shown above - that would ensure that the backup contained all versions of a document, not just the latest versions once a week.